# cURL command in PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm using this cURL command in command line and it works.

```
curl --data-binary @/opt/test.xml http://xxxxxxxxxxx/gateway/submit?source=source&conversationId=3039350
```

But how do I execute this using PHP cURL?

I tried this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://xxxxxxxx.xxx/xx/xx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "source=source&conversationId=6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));


// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }
```

How to include **--data-binary @/opt/test.xml** in PHP cURL?

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Are you wishing to send `binary` as the `Content-Transfer-Encoding`?

Comment: I read some where I will have to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded if I'm sending it binary data

Comment: @Scriptable: I'm not getting any errors. But I will need to include the test.xml part in the PHP cURL

Answer (score 0):

```
$postdata = array('source' => 'source', 'conversationId' => '6', 'file_contents' => '@' . realpath('/opt/test.xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
```